# omnetpp: Avoid "sending while transmitting" error using sendDelayed()

Tags: omnet++

I am implementing a PON in OMNet++ and I am trying to avoid the runtime error that occurs when transmitting at the time another transmission is ongoing. The only way to avoid this is by using `sendDelayed()` (or `scheduleAt()` + `send()` but I don't prefer that way).

Even though I have used `sendDelayed()` I am still getting this runtime error. My question is: when exactly the kernel checks if the channel is free if I'm using `sendDelayed(msg, startTime, out)`? It checks at `simTime() + startTime` or at `simTime()`?

I read the Simulation Manual but it is not clear about that case I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The business of the channel is checked *only* when you schedule the message (i.e. at simTime() as you asked). At this point it is checked whether the message is scheduled to be delivered at a time *after* `channel->getTransmissionFinishTime()` i.e. you can query when the currently ongoing transmission will finish and you *must* schedule the message for that time or later). But please be aware that this check is just for catching the most common errors. If you schedule for example TWO messages for the same time using sendDelayed() the kernel will check only that is starts after the *currently* transmitted message id finished, but will NOT detect that you have scheduled two or more messages for the same time after that point in time.

Generally when you transmit over a channel which has a datarate set to a non-zero time (i.e. it takes time to transmit the message), you always have to take care what happens when the messages are coming faster than the rate of the channel. In this case you should either throw away the message or you should queue it. If you queue it, then you obviously have to put it into a data structure (queue) and then schedule a self timer to be executed at the time when the message channel gets free (and the message is delivered at the other side). At this point, you should get the next packet from the queue, put it on the channel and schedule a next self timer for the time when this message is delivered.

For this reason, using just `sendDelayed()` is NOT the correct solution because you are just trying to implicitly implement a queue whit postponing the message. The problem is in this case, that once you schedule a message with sendDelay(), what delay will you use if an other packet arrives, and then another is a short timeframe? As you can see, you are implicitly creating a queue here by postponing the event. You are just using the simulation's main event queue to store the packets but it is much more convoluted an error prone.

Long story short, create a queue and schedule self event to manage the queue content properly or drop the packets if that suits your need.